# Image In Scroll View

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiscrollview

I am using the following code to try and display an image in a UIScrollView.

```
[self.jarView addSubview:imgView];
```

It does not work. However, it works when I add the subview to my normal view. My UIScrollView is called jarView and imgView is a UIImageView.

Thanks

Comment: If it works with normal view, then problem is in `self.jarView`. Check your property, outlet, init method.

Comment: @beryllium What is the init method?? Does the ScrollView need to be initialized? My image is properly initialized. The scrollview is created in Interface Builder.

Comment: Is the scrollview linked to the IBOutlet jarView in interface builder?

Comment: @JacobJennings,Yes, but what is the delegate in the scrollview?

Comment: The delegate should not affect the ability to add subviews.  http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html

Comment: @JacobJennings, So it should not matter? Here is the full code: `NSMutableArray *imagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i=0; i<10; ++i) {
        UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
            
                
                imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Aqua_Transparent"];
       
                
        imgView.frame = CGRectMake(160, 380, 25, 25);
        [self.jarView addSubview:imgView];
        [imagesArray addObject:imgView];

        [imgView release];
    }
`

Comment: Have you set the frame and contentSize of your scrollview? (and, as @JacobJennings says, have you checked that self.jarView is not nil?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine for me:

```
UIScrollView *scrollview;
scrollview= [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(,,,)];// set scroll view size
view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(y1,x1,y2,x2)];  //set the view size
UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
image=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image1];// take image size according to view
[view addSubview:image];
[scrollview addSubview:view];
[view release];
```

At last define how much `scrollview` is scroll:

```
scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(width,height);
```

Comment: 2 questions: 1) Is ScrollView and View, new or are they the existing IB objects? 2) Is y1,x1,y2,x2 the same as in the ScrollView? Thanks

Comment: here i do all programming dynamically...... i define scrollview..and allocate memory for it.... 2) y1,x1,y2,x2 coordinates i take little less from scrollview (so user can scroll).....but (view height = image height)... if this post helpful to you....don't forget Accept my answer.... you welcome always..:)

Comment: I have multiple images, that single line of code is in a for loop. Will it still work?(The images don't overlap)

Comment: What is view? is it `self.view` or is it created dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your `scrollView.contentSize` property value is set correctly (width and height should be > 0).

Answer (score 0):

I am giving you my sample code. In this code i add multiple images on scroll view and this work fine for me:

```
UIScrollView *scrollview;

- (void)anyFunction
{
    scrollview = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 30, 320, 50)];   
    NSInteger viewcount = [cat_Products count]; // if you have four content your view count is 4..(four)..in my case i fetch it from database

    CGFloat y2 = 0;
    UIView *view;
    UIImageView *imageView;
    NSString *imageName;

    for(int i = 0; i< viewcount; i++)   
    {  
        CGFloat y = i * 64;  
        y2 = y2 + 64;

        view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(y, 0, y2, 50)];

        imageName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"c%i", (i + 1)]; // my image name is c1, c2, c3, c4 so i use this

        UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];   
        imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image1];
        [view addSubview:imageView];
        [scrollview addSubview:view];
        [view release];
        [imageView release];
        [imageName release];
    }    

scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(viewcount*64,0);  //viewcount*64 because i use image width 64..and  second parameter is 0..because i not wants vertical scrolling... 
[myView addSubview:scrollview];
[scrollview release];
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here I am posting my answer. Try it.

You can load all the images to an array. And you can design a view having one image view and try the below code:

array name: examplearray and view name :exampleview

```
-(void)updateImagesInScrollView
{
     int cnt = [examplearray count];

    for(int j=0; j< cnt; ++j)
    {
        NSArray *nibContents = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"exampleview" 
                                                             owner:self 
                                                           options:nil];

        UIView *myView = [nibContents objectAtIndex:0];
        exampleview * rview= (exampleview *)myView;
        /* you can get your image from the array and set the image*/ 
        rview.imageview.image = yourimage;
        /*adding the view to your scrollview*/
        [self.ScrollView addSubview:rview];
    }
    /* you need to set  the content size of the scroll view */
    self.ScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(X, self.mHorizontalScrollView.contentSize.height);
}
```