# related to UIScrollview with UIImageView

Tags: ios, ipad

I am developing a shopping apps. Similar to something like Fab app in the iStore. I have placed a UIscrollview to which i have added 4 UIimageview and adding them as subviews to the UIScrollview. Now as user scroll need to load different images(i.e different products for sale). How do i achieve this. Then how to add buttons to this images and title.

Comment: Where are you loading your images from?

Comment: Images are there within the project itself

Answer (score 0):

See the following links to get the  How to use UIScrollView to show different images on scroll?

[Images in UIScrollview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10207814/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-show-different-images-on-scroll)
[Images Change in UIScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8260657/image-in-scroll-view)

To add button and tittle to image, just add uibutton as addsubView to ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this projects : 
[Project 1](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/60414145/ButtonManager.zip)
[Project 2](https://github.com/DavidSkrundz/uiscrollview-grid-alignment)

Then when you need to add the title, add it as subview for the images. In the project I sent you, the images are added as `UIButton` frame. Try it.